# How to know if a music is currently playing on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am currently building an application for Windows Phone 7 which has to play music with the MediaPlayer.

However, I would like to know whether the phone is already playing some music, to ask the user if he want to play also my app's.

How could I get this information?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MediaPlayer.Queue.ActiveSong should do the trick.

MediaPlayer doco [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer_members.aspx) for your reference.