# How to know if Music is currently playing on wp7 using XNA

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

I have seen a similar query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397923/how-to-know-if-a-music-is-currently-playing-on-windows-phone-7) 
But I want to use XNA framework to detect if music is currently playing on the device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MediaPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer_members.aspx) IS in the XNA Framework.